# Laravel sluggable

Tags: php, laravel, slug, slugify

I am using [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) for slugs in my Laravel 5.5 app. I was upgrading from Laravel 4.2 and I followed upgrade instructions, so now I have this in my model:

```
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => ['id', 'title'],
            'separator'  => '-',
        ]
    ];
}
```

but my models don't read `id` at all in the slug when creating.

Before when I'd save a model, I would have `123456-model`, and now I am getting just `model` without prepended ID.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're also using the Sluggable trait in your model?

Comment: I'd suggest looking here: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/issues/49  It looks like the slug is saved on creation, which means the ID doesn't exist yet.

Comment: That was resolved before with `resluggify()` but now that doesn't work as I am getting an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::reslugify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by setting the slug to null and then saving the model (only after the model was already in the DB).

```
$model = new Model(...);
...
$model->save(); // <-- initial DB insert so that model has ID

// resluggify
$model->slug = null;
$model->save();
```